# MongoDB query on join

Tags: node.js, mongodb, join, mongoose, filter

This is an abstract example, but if someone can help me to solve it, I will be eternally grateful.

I am trying to do a search based on a field in a related record. In this example we have a hierarchy  of subjects, that are nested using the parent_subject field. This is the Mongoose definition I have used:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var subjectSchema = new Schema({
   url: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
   title: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
   parent_subject: this  
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Subject', subjectSchema);
```

Some records in my MongoDB:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a3857f1afeb498c9533aef1"),
  "title" : "Sport",
  "url" : "sport",
  "__v" : 0
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a3d9a409c0973976f7889c6"),
  "title" : "Cycling",
  "__v" : 0,
  "parent_subject" : ObjectId("5a3857f1afeb498c9533aef1"),
  "url" : "cycling"
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a3d9a7e9c0973976f788b48"),
  "title" : "Mountain Biking",
  "__v" : 0,
  "parent_subject" : ObjectId("5a3d9a409c0973976f7889c6"),
  "url" : "mountain biking"
}
```

I would like to know how I can query this data based on a field in the parent record. For example, I would like to find all the subjects that have a parent subject with the title "Sport". In SQL, I would do the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM subject 
    INNER JOIN subject AS parentSubject
        ON subject.parent_subject = parentSubject.id
WHERE parentSubject.title = "Sport";
```

How would I achieve this with a MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

You can use mongodb aggregate pipeline and lookup for this

```
`Subject.aggregate([
  {
   $lookup:
     {
       from: "parentSubject",
       localField: "parent_subject",
       foreignField: "id"
       as: "parentSubject"
     }
},
{$unwind:"$parentSubject"},
{$match:{"$parentSubject.title":"Sport"}}
])`
```

For more reference you can see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html

Comment: While technically correct, this answer endorses bad data modelling, overnormalized data, to be precise.

Answer (score -1):

The point of mongoDB is that it is NOSQl, so that you also cannot use joins.
Your best option would be to first acquire the parentSubject and it's `id`.
And afterwards go for the subjects related to that `id`.

Since your data already has a `subject.parent_subject` it should be pretty easy to do.